# JS Direct access to Concat method

Tags: javascript, string, google-chrome, firefox, prototype

Considering the following code:

`var foo = String.concat("foo","bar");`

Why this works fine on Mozilla Firefox, but i get "Uncaught TypeError: String.concat is not a function" when running on Google Chrome? Alternatively, booth works fine with:

`var foo = String.prototype.concat("foo","bar");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put simply, because Firefox is doing something non-standard with the [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) object.

> The String instance methods are also available in Firefox as of JavaScript 1.6 (not part of the ECMAScript standard) on the String object for applying String methods to any object:

There is a shim located on the above-linked page to provide these instance methods on the generic `String`. It's use is not recommended. Use the standardised way of executing methods on string instances such as

```
var foobar = "foo".concat("bar")
```

Comment: Yeap, but on my case, i need to concat two number, as string - to avoid summing they. I.E.:

`var a = [1,2,3,4];`
`var foo = String.concat(a[0], a[1]); //Produces 12 - Not 3`

In this case, do i need to use:
`var a = [1,2,3,4];`
`var foo = String.prototype.concat(a[0], a[1]);`

Right?

Comment: a[0].toString().concat(a[1].toString())

Answer (score 0):

Concat is an instance method.   Firefox is doing something wrong letting you call it that way.   Try

```
"foo".concat("bar") // "foobar"
```

or

```
var x = "foo";
x.concat("bar"); // "foobar"
```

You shouldn't be able to call prototype methods from the constructor object directly.